# Attempted to autoincrement an integer value but returend null, how do I fix?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
tblcustomer = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer
        (
         CustomerID INT,
         CustomerName TEXT,
         Address TEXT,
         Postcode TEXT,
         EmailAddress TEXT,
         primary key(CustomerID AUTOINCREMENT)
         )"""

cursor.execute(tblcustomer)
connection.commit()
```

This is my table (I'm using sqlite3), but it returns 'null' to the table values. For my user inputs I just asked for the other 4 values and inserted them into the table, omitting 'CustomerID'. How do I fix it so it actually autoincrements?

Comment: Change INT to INTEGER.

Comment: Just use [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY `](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). Avoid `AUTOINCREMENT` unless you really need [its special behavior](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) (it has an unfortunately misleading name)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your table to include an AUTOINCREMENT column for the CustomerID field:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer(
CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
CustomerName TEXT,
Address TEXT,
Postcode TEXT,
EmailAddress TEXT)
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I do it for multiple primary keys?  I tried  the it the same way as you said for 2 and it said this;  sqlite3.OperationalError: table "Order" has more than one primary key.  The second primary key in 'table order' is 'CustomerID', so it is a foreign key too.

Comment: you can define a composite primary key, which is a primary key that is made up of multiple columns. To do this, you can use the PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, ...) syntax when creating the table. For example: CREATE TABLE Order (
   OrderID INTEGER,
   CustomerID INTEGER,
   OrderDate DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, CustomerID)
);